# Canceling search using a cancellationToken

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

my challenge is a rather common one, I have a heavily populated treeview that i want to filter. To do this i want to have a text box that the user enters in their filter text and after the treeview is filtered to show nodes with that particular filter text in their header.

so what i've opted to do is to have a textbox that then has a text change event that has a delay before it starts it filtering process, now obviously if the filter text changes before the delay finishes i want to cancel the process and start a new one with the new fitler text.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace pav.skillsToCompetenciesMapper.Views
{
    public partial class MapSkillsPage : Page
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts;

        private async void Search_TEXTBOX_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cts != null) cts.Cancel();
            var searchText = Search_TEXTBOX.Text;

            try
            {
                using (cts = cts ?? new CancellationTokenSource())
                    await Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token).ContinueWith(tr =>
                    {
                        var st = searchText;
                        //Do search here
                    }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled);

            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
            finally { cts = null; }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the above seems to work for me, I'm just worried that this try catch solution is a bit clunky, it really seems as if i should be able to use the TaskContinuation.OnlyOnCanceled to avoid using a try catch for logic. just seems like a code smell to me, but that's a side note.

My real problem occurs when i try to actually search the Treeview like so where the above "Do Search Here" comment is

```
foreach (TreeViewItem category in Abilities_TreeView.Items)
    foreach (DragableTreeViewItem ability in category.Items)
        if (!ability.Header.ToString().Contains(filterText))
            ability.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, my suspicion is that it has something to do with trying to access the UI thread from a background thread, but i'm not 100% sure if i'm barking up the right tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to handle the `OperationCanceledException`, you could use the overload of the `ContinueWith` method that only accepts a continuation action and check the value of the `IsCanceled` property inside this action:

```
try
{
    using (cts = cts ?? new CancellationTokenSource())
        await Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token).ContinueWith(tr =>
        {
            if (!tr.IsCanceled)
            {
                var st = searchText;
                //Do search here
            }
        });
}
finally { cts = null; }
```

> thanks, sorry i was a bit trigger happy, and didn't finish asking my question

You can't access the `TreeView` from any other thread than the dispatcher thread that it was originally created on, but you can make sure that the continuation action will be executed on this thread by using an overload that accepts a `TaskScheduler`:

```
await Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token).ContinueWith(tr =>
{
    if (!tr.IsCanceled)
    {
        var st = searchText;
        //Do search here
    }
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: thanks, sorry i was a bit trigger happy, and didn't finish asking my question.

Comment: See my edit. But please ask a new question if you have another issue than the one that was stated in your original question.